# RichCopy - Suppress Splash Screen and Run Quiet?

Tags: backup, copy, robocopy

RichCopy looks to be a great tool with some features that RoboCopy lacks. I'm trying to use it to back up media on a Home Media Server project I'm working on so I need to be able to run it from command line and without any visual impact. I'm fairly surprised that this is not a common requirement and it looks like the developers have not provided for this. Has anyone who has used RichCopy found a way to run it quiet? Maybe I could force it to appear offscreen, but I'd rather not go that route.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this link can help:

http://file.serverconsolidator.com/blog/2009/08/11/the-easiest-way-to-prepare-richcopy-command-line-parameters/

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to run RichCopy in a very very very small window (just the size of the control boxes) by amending the registry "Frame" btye.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You could use `PSExec` to have the RichCopy run in the background. That's what I'm doing so I can execute a bunch of long-running RichCopy jobs on remote servers without hogging up RDP sessions. You may also be able to set up an AutoHotKey script to hide the RichCopy GUI and splash screen.

Comment: Can I ask what options you are using for PSExec?  I've tried the -i (interactive) with and without the <session> and -d (don't wait /non-interactive) without success.